Is it harmful to cook frozen meat directly?
I tried cooking frozen chicken breast directly in an air fryer, and it tasted great. But after eating it, my younger brother had an upset stomach and a lot of pain, while the rest of us were fine. So, is it actually bad for health to cook frozen meat directly, or did this happen because my younger brother has a weaker digestion?

What was the internal temperature when you took it out?
